# Hydrological catchment area for a road segment (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, hydrology, watershed, catchment-area

I try to calculate the hydrological catchment areas for road segments in a mountainous region in QGIS. As far as I see, I can only calculate watersheds in general or for particular points. Is there a more elegant solution than calculating the upslope areas for multiple points along the road segment and merging them?

[image: Screenshot with an example of such a road segment]

Comment: I'd like to get the contributing upslope area for a line feature (a road segment, the orange line in the screenshot I added to the original post). I only found out how I can calculate those watersheds/catchment areas for single points (as the pink ones in the screenshot) with SAGA, GRASS and Whitebox, but I am looking for a way to calculate it for a linear feature, that isn't part of a stream or channel network.
The reason behind this procedure is research about erosion on forest roads.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, I believe, calculate upstream drainage area for a line feature. A road segment could, for example, cross over a ridge such that parts of the line segment would be in one watershed, and parts in a different watershed. What would the upstream flow accumulation area be in that case? (Similarly you cannot get the elevation for a whole line segment. Only the average elevation or elevation at end points can be found.)

The usual way to address this is to prepare a dense stream network, and intersect the roads and streams. Then loop thru those intersection points and find the upstream flow accumulation for each. After all erosion would normally occur only where stream flows actually cross the road...